# How to make a custom button for pressed and released at android?

Tags: java, android, button

I know there are many questions of this kind here, but I really dont know the reason that my code is not working.
I'm trying to make a button with three states: normal, pressed and released. When I say released, I mean that I would like to make this like a toogle button, with the states `active` and `not active`.

When I release the button, it returns to the default state. I would like to change the image by click, as a checkButton works.

I tried this:

http://blog.androgames.net/40/custom-button-style-and-theme/

http://www.gersic.com/blog.php?id=56

[Android: How to Create a Custom button widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007507/android-how-to-create-a-custom-button-widget)

http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2010/03/custom-buttons-on-android.html

custom_buttom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/focussed" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/focussedandpressed" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/pressed" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/default" />
</selector>
```

layout.xml:

```
 <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/menu"
                    android:layout_weight="1" android:background="@drawable/custom_button"></Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `android:state_focused` and `android:state_pressed`.

What about [android:state_checked](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html#attr_android%3astate_checked)?

Comment: I tried this: `<item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/notcheckedimage" />
 <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/checkedimage" />`

Answer (score 0):

You want custom something like Checkbox, right? In that case, you need two image for state check true and false, and a transparent file for background (which have no content, just has the same size as other images). Create two drawable selector file have content like this:

**background_selector.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/your_bg" />

</selector>
```

**state_selector.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_on" />

    <item android:state_checked="false" android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_off" />

    <item android:state_checked="false" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_off" />

    <item android:state_checked="true" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_on" />

</selector>
```

Put these xml to your drawable folder, and in your layout, create a checkbox:

```
<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="50dip"
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:background="@drawable/background_selector"
    android:button="@drawable/state_selector"
/>
```

Hope this help ^_^